# Redis cluster between 2 servers, Waiting for the cluster to join takes forever

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, software-distribution

I want to make redis cluster,
I have 2 server and each server have 3 redis (for 3 masters & 3 slaves).

Let's say :

- server 1 : IP 10.27.62.95 (redis port : 7000, 7002, 7003)
- server 2 : IP 10.27.62.124 (redis port : 7001, 7004, 7005)

Firewall is not running.

I run cluster create on server 2

```
./redis-cli --cluster create 10.27.62.95:7000 10.27.62.124:7001 10.27.62.95:7002 10.27.62.95:7003 10.27.62.124:7004 10.27.62.124:7005 --cluster-replicas 1
```

[image]

and after I type yes, this is happen
[image]

it takes forever waiting for the cluster to join

here is one of my redis.conf

```
protected-mode no
port 7001
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
daemonize no
loglevel notice
logfile /home/redis2/redis-log.log
databases 16
always-show-logo no
set-proc-title yes
proc-title-template "{title} {listen-addr} {server-mode}"
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
rdb-del-sync-files no
dir ./
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-diskless-load disabled
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
replica-priority 100
acllog-max-len 128
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no
lazyfree-lazy-user-del no
lazyfree-lazy-user-flush no
oom-score-adj no
oom-score-adj-values 0 200 800
disable-thp yes
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
lua-time-limit 5000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-node-timeout 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4096
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
rdb-save-incremental-fsync yes
jemalloc-bg-thread yes
```

I don't understand why this happen, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I knew the answer,
I haven't open the offset bus port 10000, so redis keep trying to join forever

Comment: and yes, after I open the port, the cluster join immediately